# How do I read a text/CSV file and ignore the "\n" in java

Tags: java

I am using bufferedreader to capture the text in a CSV file and a Scanner to assign it to a variable so I can save it to an array later, the file has three values, **a number, a name, and a "price"** but when I read the "price" it captures the *"price" \n number* which throws off  everything, how do I stop reading \n without using ".nextLine"
The code looks like this

```
    try {
        File file = new File("...\\file.csv");
        FileReader printReader = new FileReader(file); 
        BufferedReader BuffReader = new BufferedReader(printReader);
        Scanner Writer = new Scanner(BuffReader);
        
        //get max number of iteams in the file
        Writer.useDelimiter(",");
        String num = Writer.next();
        int max=Integer.parseInt(num);
        System.out.println(num + " Max");
        
        /*start Random
        Random rand = new Random();
        int min;
        min = 1;
        int Amount = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        System.out.println(Amount + " Amount");*/
        String Item = Writer.next();        //get the name of the iteam 
        System.out.println(Item + " Item1"); //print item
        String Price = Writer.next();           ///get  price of the item...this is were the error occurs
        System.out.println(Price + " Price1"); //print price
        num = Writer.next();                    //Suppose to get the number of the item
        int Num=Integer.parseInt(num);      //conver to an int
        System.out.println(Num + " Num");
        Item = Writer.next();           
        System.out.println(Item + " Item2");
        Price = Writer.next();          
        System.out.println(Price + " Price2");
        
      BuffReader.close();
      Writer.close();
    }
```

the example for the CSV/txtfile is

116,item,Price

1,item2,price2

2,item3,price

my goal is to choose a random item from this list using a util.Random, and checking what number it is using the first number in the txt file and saving the team and price to an array

Comment: It is better to use a csv library e.g. http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVReader.html

Comment: Do you have to use a `Scanner` and a `BufferedReader`? You could alternatively use [`java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Path, Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) and just receive the lines of the file as a `List<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\n` as an additional delimiter besides `,`. Simply change this line of code:

```
Writer.useDelimiter(",");
```

to this one:

```
Writer.useDelimiter("(,|\n)");
```

With this `next()` reads three values in each line and does not combine the last and first value of two lines.